# Why do we multiply probabilities here for a sequence containing $n$ black balls and $n-k$ white balls?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I am studying the hypergeometric distribution, and my textbook introduces this by analyzing an urn with $N=B+W$ balls, where $B$ is the number of black balls and $W$ the number of white balls. When we sample $n$ balls from the urn without replacement, it is stated that the probability of sampling a particular sequence containing $k$ black balls and $n-k$ white balls is $$\frac{B}{N} \times \frac{B-1}{N-1} \times \cdots \times \frac{B-k+1}{N-k+1} \times \frac{W}{N-k} \times \frac{W-1}{N-k-1} \times \cdots \times \frac{W-(n-k)+1}{N-n+1}$$

I was wondering why we are multiplying the probabilities here. We multiply when our events are independent, but here the event of the $i$th ball being black isn't independent with the event of the $(i+1)$st ball being black. Is it still the case that some events are independent here, which is why we multiply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*We multiply [only] when our events are independent*"  Mostly false.  We are perfectly allowed to multiply in all cases... it is just that in the specific case of independent events that the multiplications are of the original untouched probabilities... that $\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A)\times \Pr(B)$ for independent events.  While it is correct to say that $\Pr(A\cap B)$ is not equal to $\Pr(A)\times \Pr(B)$ under normal circumstances... it is *always* true that $\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A)\times \Pr(B\mid A)$ using conditional probabilities.

Here, these probabilities being multiplied are the conditional probabilities that chain together as per multiplication principle of probability or multiplication principle of counting depending on your preferred outlook.

If this is still too foreign to grasp... consider instead treating this large expression as a single fraction... $\dfrac{B\times (B-1)\times \cdots \times (B-k+1)\cdots}{N\times (N-1)\times \dots \times (N-k+1)\cdots}$ and consider the naive counting approach to probability (*in equiprobable sample spaces like this*) noting how the numerator and denominator count outcomes.

It is worth pointing out as well here for the hypergeometric distribution that we could *heavily* simplify things by treating order of results as irrelevant (*which is perfectly fine to do so long as you are consistent with doing that for both your numerator and your denominator*) at which point you can use binomial coefficients when counting to get the far more concise value of

$$\frac{\binom{B}{k}\binom{W}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}$$